# How To Retrieve Data from Json Array In Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

1. This Is My Code I want to Retrieve FirstName, ComapnyName, Designation, 
   PersonalEmail and PersonalWebsite

   ```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {
           $e = array();
           $e[]  = $index;
           $e[]  = $row["FirstName"];
           $e[]  = $row["CompanyName"]; 
           $e[]  = $row["Designation"] ;
           $e[]  = $row["PersonalEmail"]; 
           $e[]  = $row["PersonalWebsite"] ; 
           $data[] = $e;
           $index++;
     }

   $json_data = array(
                     "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   
                     "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ), 
                     "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ),
                     "data"            => $data //How To Retrieve This Data
                    );

   echo json_encode($json_data);
   ```
2. I want to Retrieve data here

   ```
    $.ajax({
           url:'assets/ajax/contact_list-load.php',
           async:false,
           success:function(result)
               {
           //I want to use all data here
               }
        )},
   ```

Comment: this is the server side in php. Isn't it? 
In the server side you must to return<? json_encode($json_data);?>

Comment: Ok My bad i Have not put all code actually i did that i Will edit my question with all code

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:
In your html must import it

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

and then

```
<script>
$.ajax({
url: "pathtoyourfileWhereIsYour.php",
context: document.body
}).done(function(data) {
 $('body').append( "<div>" + data.draw + "</div>" );
 $('body').append( "<div>" + data.recordsTotal + "</div>" );
});
</script>
```